# how to round to two decimal places in java

Tags: java

final double YearDep= 0.15; //this is for each year a car loses of the value before

```
     double HybridDepreciation= HybridCarCost * Math.pow(1-YearDep,5);
     double HybridFuelCost=(Miles*5*GasCost)/HybridCarMPG;

     double GasPowerDepreciation=GasPowerCost * Math.pow(1-YearDep,5);
     double GasPowerFuelCost=(Miles *5*GasCost)/GasPowerMPG;

     double HybridTotalCost=HybridCarCost - HybridDepreciation + HybridFuelCost;
     double GasPowerTotalCost= GasPowerCost - GasPowerDepreciation + GasPowerFuelCost;

     System.out.printf("The total cost for the " + HybridName + " " + "is" +" $"+ HybridTotalCost);

     System.out.println();
     System.out.printf("The total cost for the " + GasPowerName + " "+ "is" + " $"+ GasPowerTotalCost);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00");
System.out.printf("The total cost for the " + HybridName + " " + "is" +" $"+ df.format(HybridTotalCost));
 System.out.println();
 System.out.printf("The total cost for the " + GasPowerName + " "+ "is" + " $"+ df.format(GasPowerTotalCost));
```

Or you can use

```
String.format("The total cost for the  %s is $%.2f", HybridName ,HybridTotalCost)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 double roundOff = Math.round(a*100)/100.0;
```

or

```
 DecimalFormat number = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
 number.format(new Double(2223.8990))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

then

```
df.format(<your_value>);
```

Or

```
System.out.println( String.format( "%.2f", <your_value> ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
double roundOff1 = (double) Math.round(HybridTotalCost);
double roundOff2 = (double) Math.round(GasPowerTotalCost);
```

and you can also use.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
System.out.printf("The total cost for the " + HybridName + " " + "is" +" $"+ df.format(HybridTotalCost));
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("The total cost for the " + GasPowerName + " "+ "is" + " $"+df.format(GasPowerTotalCost));
```